# Spix - Qt UI testing framework build

Tags: c++, visual-studio, qt

Does anyone managed to build and link [Spix](https://github.com/faaxm/spix) library using Visual Studio?
For me, the build works, but when I try to link against it in QT, I'm getting a lot of link errors

```
Eg Spix.lib(socket.obj):-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp__accept@12 referenced in function "public: unsigned int __thiscall anyrpc::TcpSocket::Accept(void)" (?Accept@TcpSocket@anyrpc@@QAEIXZ)
```

Included in .pro the lib

```
INCLUDEPATH += \
    $$PWD/libs/spix/include \
DEPENDPATH += \
    $$PWD/libs/spix/ \
LIBS += -L$$PWD/libs/spix/ -lSpix
```

VS general settings:

[image: generalsettings]

VS librarian settings:

[image: librariansettings]

Answer (score 0):

I notice this is your first question. Thanks for stopping by!

I think what you need is to add `-lanyrpc` to your `LIBS` for your executable. You have it listed in your dependencies for the another static library (presumably `Spix.lib`), but I don't think it is being merged in there. Your executable needs those symbols.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I already tried this, but no effects

Comment: Are there any other error or warning messages from the build when you have both static libs in your exe's `LIBS`? Can you show the executable's linker settings in Visual Studio?

Comment: I'm getting the exactly same errors with both static libs. For executable I'm not using VS, I'm using QT Creator and I cannot see linker settings

Comment: Solved. The problem was that I missed to link ws2_32.lib too.

Comment: So, you needed to add `-lanyrpc -lws2_32` to your exe's `LIBS`?

Comment: Actually, I merged ws2_32.lib into anyrpc.lib